# Access Query Filtering

Tags: ms-access

Create a query on access to display the cities of clients in ascending order. Each city should appear only once.

I think you can filter further in query properties I am just not sure exactly how to do it any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use Access query builder Design Grid or type in SQL View. Very basic Access functionality.

Two possible query syntax.

DISTINCT can be invoked in the Property Sheet with the Unique Values property.
`SELECT DISTINCT City FROM tablename ORDER BY City;`

Grouping can be invoked by clicking the Sigma(Totals) icon on Design tab.
`SELECT City FROM tablename GROUP BY City ORDER BY City;`